# Can't get aggregate functions to work

Tags: php, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm completely new to Mongo, and I'm having some serious trouble wrapping my head around the Aggregation Framework. I have a document that looks like this:

```
record {
    _id: '2013-04-22/tacos',
    first: {
        something: {0: 1, 1:4},
        somethingelse: {0: 18, 1:22}
    },
    second: {
        0: [11, 18, 7],
        1: [17, 9, 22]
    },
    metadata: {
        date: '2013-04-22'
    }
}
```

What I want to do is get sums (since this will need to work with multiple documents) of each item in first.something, each item in second, and then sums of all items in `first.something`, `second.<whatever>.0`, `second.<whatever>.1`, and `second.<whatever>.2`. So I'm looking for a result like this (pardon my formatting):

```
sum(first.something.0):      1
sum(first.something.1):      4
sum(second.0.0):            11
sum(second.0.1):            18
sum(second.0.2):             7
sum(second.1.0):            17
sum(second.1.1):             9
sum(second.1.2):            22
sum(first.something.all):    5
sum(second.<whatever>.0):   28
sum(second.<whatever>.1):   27
sum(second.<whatever>.2):   29
```

Right now I'm just trying to get the first two working, on a single record, and I've got this:

```
// $db is my collection, and is verified to work
$aggregate = array(
    '$group' => array(
        '_id' => '$metadata.date',
        'first_zero' => array('$sum' => 'first.something.0'),
        'first_one' => array('$sum' => 'first.something.1')
    ),
    '$match' => array(
        "metadata.date" => '2013-04-22'
    )
);
$cursor = $db->aggregate($aggregate);
var_dump($cursor);
```

However my output tells me `exception: A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field.`. But if I leave out the `'$match'` part, it returns the record with int(0) for `first_zero` and `first_one` as shown:

```
array(2) {
  ["result"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["_id"]=>
      string(10) "2013-04-22"
      ["clicks_zero"]=>
      int(0)
      ["clicks_one"]=>
      int(0)
    }
  }
  ["ok"]=>
  float(1)
}
```

So I can't even get the simple part working. What am I doing wrong here? And is the `second.<whatever>.0` even a thing I can do?

Comment: if you only intend to keep the one date, why not move the $match first in the pipeline?  I also would recommend working out the aggregation in the shell first so that you know whether the problem is with your pipeline or with your PHP...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm no expert in Php but should the aggregation query look like:

```
  $aggregate = array(
      array('$group' => array(
          '_id' => '$metadata.date',
          'first_zero' => array('$sum' => 'first.something.0'),
          'first_one' => array('$sum' => 'first.something.1')
      )),
      array('$match' => array(
          "metadata.date" => '2013-04-22'
      ))
  );
```

Each pipeline operator should be inside a hash/array.

**Edit**

However, the above would give you no result because of the `$match` pipeline at the end. There is no `metadata.date` field that is created in the previous pipeline, so no results will match your query. The right solution would be:

```
  $aggregate = array(
      array('$match' => array(
          "metadata.date" => '2013-04-22'
      )),
      array('$group' => array(
          '_id' => '$metadata.date',
          'first_zero' => array('$sum' => 'first.something.0'),
          'first_one' => array('$sum' => 'first.something.1')
      ))
  );
```

Which will give you:

```
{
"result" : [
    {
        "_id" : "2013-04-22",
        "first_zero" : 1,
        "first_one" : 4
    }
],
"ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: I agree , each pipeline should be an array with key value pair. I had faced the same issue few days back

Comment: Nope, still getting zeros even after adding in the missing comma between $match and $group

Comment: Interesting... I used the same record in your example, although I did check it only using the mongo shell. Have you tried running it on the mongo shell (you need to use the js syntax)?

Comment: Turns out the problem is that I defined first.something as [1,4] rather than as {0:1,1:4}. That's so weird, but it's not something that's going to come up in the production environment.